# SSL cert with same finger print but different serial number

Tags: ssl, certificate, websphere

New to websphere. Trying to install and validate root and chain cert in cell default trust store. I have root and chain cert installed already with same finger print but both cert having different serial number from my other root and chain.

So question is here — are cert same if they have same finger print? What if they have different serial number?

Answer (score 1):

If a certificate has a different serial number it also has a different *certificate* fingerprint - which is a hash over the whole certificate including the serial number. It might have the same *public key* fingerprint though since the same key pair can be used to generate multiple certificates - since the public key fingerprint is only a hash over the public key and does not include information like serial number. It is not uncommon to keep the key when renewing a certificate.